# Controls Based Security in a Windows Forms Application using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

I need to implement, Controls Based Security in a Windows Forms Application using VB.NET. I tried google but did not get anything much to work with.

I would like if someone, could suggest some books or tutorials.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at Jesse Liberty's very detailed article: [Controls Based Security in a Windows Forms Application](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/windows-forms/controls-based-security-in-a-windows-forms-application/), which includes full source and demonstrates one nice approach to this problem.  While the article is in C#, the concepts should all translate to VB.NET exactly.

Comment: Very insecure, trivially hacked with a tool like ManagedSpy.  Setting a control's Visible or Enabled property isn't good enough, it should never be created.

Comment: @Hans: True, but that tends to be a problem with controls based security in general.  I wouldn't rely on this as the only level of security in an application - for example, I'd still expect any data mechanism to have it's own security policy in addition to this.